Find $\angle NMC$
Let $\triangle ABC$ issoscel with $AB=AC$, s.t. $\angle A=48^{\circ}$ and $M$ a point inside the triangle such that $\angle ABM=36^{\circ}$, $\angle ACM=18^{\circ}$. Let $N$ the middle of $AB$.
Find $\angle NMC$.
I tried to apply Sine Law, but I am stuck.


The posted question is inconsistent with the diagram.  Is there a typo in the posted question?  That is, you have posted that $~\angle ACM = 36^\circ,~$ while the diagram indicates that $~\angle ACM = 18^\circ.$

Carve your triangle $ABC$ out of regular pentagon $ADEFC$ plus equilateral triangle $ABD$.
Note that $M$ lies on line $CD$. Angle chasing yields that $BMD$ is isoceles, and so is $AMD$. Thus $\measuredangle MAB = 12^\circ$, and, in the end, $ACM$ is isosceles, as well. This makes $\measuredangle NMC = 54^\circ$. We already know by angle chasing that $\measuredangle CMB = 102^\circ$. Hence
$$\boxed{\measuredangle NMC = 156^\circ.}$$


Hint: Apply the trigonometric form of Ceva's theorem to show that $\angle MAC = 12^\circ, \angle MAN = 36^\circ$.
So $MN$ is the perpendicular bisector of $AB$, and $x = 90 ^ \circ - 36^\circ = 54^\circ$, $\angle NMC = 106^\circ$.

Alternative solution: Continuing from OP's work, we want to determine $x$ such that
$$ \frac{ 2 (\sin 48^\circ)^2}{\sin 66^\circ \sin 78^\circ} = \frac{ \sin (36^\circ +x) }{ \sin x }  = \cos 36^\circ + \cot x \sin 36^\circ. $$
Since the RHS is decreasing in $ x \in [ 0 ^ \circ,90^\circ]$, it has a unique solution there. And if this solution is $< 54^\circ$, then we might have 2 possibilities.
We will show that $ x = 54^\circ $ works.
$$\begin{array} {ll} WTS & 2 \sin 48^\circ \sin 48^\circ \sin 54^\circ = \sin 66^\circ \sin 78^\circ \\
\Leftrightarrow & 4 \sin 24^\circ \cos 24^\circ \sin 48^\circ \sin 54^\circ = \sin 66^\circ \sin 78^\circ\\
\Leftrightarrow &8 \sin 12^\circ \cos 12^\circ \sin 48^\circ \sin 54^\circ = \sin 78^\circ \\
\Leftrightarrow &8 \sin 12^\circ \sin 48^\circ \sin 54^\circ = 1\\
\Leftrightarrow &4 ( \cos 36^\circ - \cos 60^\circ) \sin 54^\circ = 1\\
\Leftrightarrow & 4 \sin^2 54^\circ - 2 \sin^2 54^\circ = 1\\
\Leftarrow & \sin 54^\circ = \frac{ 1 + \sqrt{5} } { 2}.\\ \end{array} $$

@ale Also see how we can complete your solution with some perseverance (and knowing the answer).

you are fabulos :) Do you have a chanell on Youtube or a blog about math?

@ale Check out brilliant.org.


In picture $BZ$ is the bisector of angle ABM and also the diameter of circumcircle g of triangle BLM. $BC_1$is the bisector of angle LBM. Now we use the fact that the bisector of any angle in a triangle  is also the bisector of the angle between the diameter of the circumcircle  g and the altitude of triangle from the same vertex. In this way since BZ is diameter of g then BN is the altitude of triangle BLN, that is:
$\angle BNM=90^o$
$\angle NBM= 36^o$
$\Rightarrow \angle NMB=90-36=54^o$
Finally:
$\angle NMC=102+54=156^o$
